# error when trying when using mq_open on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, queue, mq

I am trying to open a queue on linux in C++ and it returns a -1 error.
how would I debug this issue.

```
 int32_t MaxMsgs;
    int32_t MaxMsgLength;
    eoMQHndlT msgQptr = -1; 
    char temp[32];
    
    mq_unlink(temp);
    
    struct mq_arrt msQAtt; msQAtt.mq_flags = 0; msQAtt.mq_maxmsg = MaxMsgs; msQAtt.mq_magsize = MaxMsgLength; msQAtt.mq_curmsgs = 0;
    
    msgQptr  = mq_open(temp,O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, &msQAtt);
```

The variables MaxMsgs and MaxMsgLength are sent it to this call and those values are ex1: MaxMsgs = 10, MaxMsgLength=1232 and ex2:MaxMsgs = 2400, MaxMsgLength=4136
Appreciate some feedback

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `mq_open` (emphasis mine):

> RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, mq_open() returns a message queue descriptor for use
> by other message queue functions.  On error, mq_open() returns
> (mqd_t) -1, **with errno set to indicate the error**.

So, to debug the issue you have, you should check the value of `errno`.

Comment: I am getting a value of  -1 for msgQptr . I am assuming that is the errno?

Comment: how do I print the errno?

Comment: No, `errno` is a separate variable that is set by various functions to indicate the specific error. `-1` just indicates that there was an error. From the return value section [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html), there is a link to the [`errno`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) manual page.

Comment: And from that page, it tells you that you can use `perror` and `strerror` to print an error message to `stderr`.

Comment: when I did perror("mq_open") - for 2 different instances I get - Too many open files and invalid argument. How do I debug this?

Comment: @jkafernando _**Too many open files ...**_ - then what might be happening is that you don't call `mq_close` after `mq_send` or `mq_receive`, there is a limit of opened file descriptors set in `/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/queues_max`, you may have exceeded that limit. Check the duplicate.